# Array in state being replaced with a 1 when setting state

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am new to React, so I apologize in advance if I'm trying to do something that cannot be done. I am trying to store an object containing an id and a score for a selection in a "scores" array in the state. I am building the object in a function called handleScore, and the state seems to be showing properly when I first click on the selection and log the score array to the console immediately afterward, but when I log the score array to the console in the render method, I'm just getting a 1. I also get a 1 when I make a selection then click the button again. Does anyone have any ideas what's going on? Here is the code:

```
    handleScore = (id, score, idx) => {
        const { statements, scores } = this.state;
        let scoreObj = {};

        Object.assign(scoreObj, {'id': id, 'score': score});

        if (statements[0][idx].isSelected) {
            this.setState({
                scores: scores[0].push(scoreObj)
            });
            console.log("scores array: ", scores[0]); //outputs an array containing [{id: "O1", score: "4"}]
        } else {
            console.log("scores array: ", scores[0]); // outputs 1
        }
    }
```

In the render() method:

```
        render() {
            console.log("this.state.scores from render method: ", this.state.scores); // outputs 1 instead of [{id: "O1", score: "4"}]
            return (
                <div>
                    <div className="statements-wrapper">
                        {
                            this.state.statements[0].map((item, index) => (
                                    <div
                                    key={item.id} onClick={(e) => {
                                                e.preventDefault();
                                                this.handleScore(item.id, match.params.score, index)
                                            }}>
                                        <a href="#">{item.statement}</a>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
```

expected output:

```
            scores: [
                [{id: "O1", score: 4}, {id: "G1", score: 3}, {id: "B1", score: 2}, {id: "R1", score: 1}],
                [{id: "O2", score: 4}, {id: "G2", score: 3}, {id: "B2", score: 2}, {id: "R2", score: 1}],
                [{id: "O3", score: 4}, {id: "G3", score: 3}, {id: "B3", score: 2}, {id: "R3", score: 1}],
                [{id: "O4", score: 4}, {id: "G4", score: 3}, {id: "B4", score: 2}, {id: "R4", score: 1}],
                [{id: "O5", score: 4}, {id: "G5", score: 3}, {id: "B5", score: 2}, {id: "R5", score: 1}]
            ]
```

Comment: you should show the initial state of `this.state.scores`

Comment: I have initialized to an array containing an empty array:

scores: [
     []
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem stems from replacing the entirety of `this.state.scores` to a single array when you use `setState`. To preserve the rest of the element arrays, you want to do something like:

```
handleScore = (id, score, idx) => {
    const { statements, scores } = this.state;
    if (statements[0][idx].isSelected) {
        // this assumes you want to append the first array (hence 'index === 0') in this.state.scores
        this.setState({
            scores: scores.map((item, index) => index === 0 ? [...item, {'id': id, 'score': score}] : item)
        });
    }
}
```

It's also important to note that the method above as well as `push` will put the new object at the *end* of the array and that `setState` is asynchronous, so console logging `scores` immediately afterward may not be reliable.

To remove a specific object within one of the inner arrays, you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
// replacing an inner object by id value
scores.map((item, index) => index === 0 ? 
  item.filter((i) => i.id !== "01")
  : item
)
```

Comment: Awesome, this definitely seems to be working more as intended.  However, what if I want to remove a score object from the array?

Comment: I appended the answer

Comment: Thanks! It works! But just so I can understand a little better what's going on: So index === 0 identifies the first array and I am using the spread operator to create the array and add the object inside; otherwise, create the array empty? So if I want to populate another array I can dynamically set index === 1, index === 2, etc. etc.?

Comment: `map` allows you to iterate through an array, then make changes to each element and return the modified array. Our inner qualifying statement is just shorthand for "if it's the first element, then change this element to the modified array, otherwise just leave the element untouched." You change/add to the logic however you want. I'd appreciate it if you mark this answer as the accepted answer.